# how do I extract a tar archive with larger block size?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, backup-restoration, tar

I have a tar ball that has a huge number of very large files. The blocking factor is 10k. This is taking too long to extract because it does a lot of 10k writes. The filesystem will perform better if I get larger writes in one shot. If tar cannot let me do larger writes, how do I use some other bash piping technique to extract to memory and flush larger blocks to disk?

Comment: The blocking factor != block size! You ask for the blocking factor, not the block size. The block size is always 512 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `-b` switch of `tar`:

```
 -b, --blocking-factor BLOCKS
       BLOCKS x 512 bytes per record
```

Now your command will look like this:

`tar xfv mybigbigtar.tar --blocking-factor=<whatever you desire>`